# Execution Failed for task :app:compileDebugJavaWithJavac in Android Studio whhile making object detection app

Tags: flutter, dart, detection, tflite

here is error:

```
The plugin tflite uses a deprecated version of the Android embedding.
To avoid unexpected runtime failures, or future build failures, try to see if this plugin supports the      Android V2 embedding. Otherwise, consider removing it since a future release of Flutter will remove these    deprecated APIs.
If you are plugin author, take a look at the docs for migrating the plugin to the V2 embedding:   https://flutter.dev/go/android-plugin-migration.
Launching lib\main.dart on CPH2285 in debug mode...
Running Gradle task 'assembleDebug'...
```

C:\nikunj\flutter_realtime_detection-    master\android\app\src\main\java\com\example\examplerealtime\MainActivity.java:11: error: incompatible    types: MainActivity cannot be converted to FlutterEngine
GeneratedPluginRegistrant.registerWith(this);
^
Note: C:\nikunj\flutter_realtime_detection-    master\android\app\src\main\java\com\example\examplerealtime\MainActivity.java uses or overrides a     deprecated API.
Note: Recompile with -Xlint:deprecation for details.
Note: Some messages have been simplified; recompile with -Xdiags:verbose to get full output
1 error

```
FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':app:compileDebugJavaWithJavac'.
> Compilation failed; see the compiler error output for details.

* Try:
Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log     output. Run with --scan to get full insights.

* Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

BUILD FAILED in 21s
Exception: Gradle task assembleDebug failed with exit code 1
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/d5Kci.png)
```

** xml manifest is here :**

```
...

def flutterVersionName = localProperties.getProperty('flutter.versionName')
if (flutterVersionName == null) {
flutterVersionName = '1.0'
}

apply plugin: 'com.android.application'
apply from: "$flutterRoot/packages/flutter_tools/gradle/flutter.gradle"
```

android {
compileSdkVersion 28

```
lintOptions {
    disable 'InvalidPackage'
}

defaultConfig {
    // TODO: Specify your own unique Application ID     (https://developer.android.com/studio/build/application-id.html).
    applicationId "com.example.examplerealtime"
    minSdkVersion 21
    targetSdkVersion 29
    versionCode flutterVersionCode.toInteger()
    versionName flutterVersionName
    testInstrumentationRunner "androidx.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
}

buildTypes {
    release {
        // TODO: Add your own signing config for the release build.
        // Signing with the debug keys for now, so `flutter run --release` works.
        signingConfig signingConfigs.debug
    }
}

aaptOptions {
    noCompress 'tflite'
    noCompress 'lite'
}
compileOptions {
    sourceCompatibility = 1.8
    targetCompatibility = 1.8
}
buildToolsVersion = '28.0.3'
}

flutter {
    source '../..'
}

dependencies {
testImplem`entation 'junit:junit:4.12'
androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.ext:junit:1.1.1'
androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.1.0'
```

}

**    i'm trying run project of object detection in app tflite. but is showing error that mentioned.**